# Limit x axis drag length for jQuery.draggable()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to limit how far I can drag an element by a pixel amount. I am looping through each child element, adding it to a sum and trying to constrain the left drag to this amount.

I cannot use parent containment, as the draggable element doesn't really need boundaries by a parent element, but by the calculated width of each tab.

This is what Ive got so far:

**JavaScript**

```
   var maxMenuWidth = 0;
   $('.tabName').each(function(index, el) {
       var menuWidth = $(this).outerWidth();

       maxMenuWidth = maxMenuWidth + menuWidth;
   });
   maxMenuWidth = maxMenuWidth;
   console.log(maxMenuWidth);

  jQuery("#TabLabels").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    cursor: "move", 
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.position.left = Math.min( 0, ui.position.left );
        ui.position.left = Math.max( maxMenuWidth, ui.position.left );
    }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="TabLabels" class="ui-draggable">
      <span class="tabName">Tab 1</span>
      <span class="tabName">Tab 2</span>
      <span class="tabName">Tab 3</span>
      <span class="tabName">Tab 4</span>
   </div>
```

I can limit the right drag, from the following line:

```
ui.position.left = Math.min( 0, ui.position.left );
```

But the next line,

```
ui.position.left = Math.max( maxMenuWidth, ui.position.left );
```

Causes the draggaable element to set an inline style at the maxMenuWidth.

Is there something like ui.position.right that would limit the drag length on the right side?

Comment: Could you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to limit this with:

```
drag: function(event, ui) {
    var leftPosition = ui.position.left;
    if (leftPosition > maxMenuWidth) {
        ui.position.left = maxMenuWidth;
    }
}
```

I've set up an example at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEBOde. Note that I've made some other minor tweaks to your code such as removing the redundant

```
maxMenuWidth = maxMenuWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#TabLabels").draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    containment: 'children',
    delay: 5,
    start: function( event, ui ) {
      $(this).addClass('my_class'); 
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
      $(this).removeClass('my_class'); 
    }
  })
```

```
.my_class{
  border: 1px soild #000 !important;
}
```